# How to accept a blank value for a Scanner input

Tags: java

I'm trying to achieve something for a small personal bank account project that I'm practicing with. I want to make it so that if a user enters a space , or doesn't enter anything at all (meaning they pressed enter without entering a value) that the default name of the account switches to "Default".

Like so:

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your account's name: ");
String input = read.next();
String name = "";

if (input == "" || input == null) {
    name = "Default";
} else {
    name = input;
}
```

Probably a stupid question, but this is one where I'm having a little trouble on. If I enter a space and then press enter, it doesn't continue to set the name. If I press enter when it prompts for an input, it doesn't continue to set the name. Is there a way to set it?

Edit: I don't want to know whether or not a String equals another string via .equals() (thank you for pointing that out, by the way). The scanner still does not accept blank inputs.

Comment: Use .equals() to compare strings

Comment: in java, == is used for primitive value equality or object reference equality.  like Sweeper mentioned, object value equality is ascertained through .equals()

Comment: True. However, regardless, I still can't input a blank character and have the Scanner accept it. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your account's name: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    String name = "";
    // System.out.println(input);
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        name = "Default";
    } else {
        name = input;
    }
System.out.println(name);
```

This works f9 try it.